# "AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'adv'" despite Phoenix

Tags: python, wxpython

Does anyone know a solution to this?

EDIT: This question was closed, because the problem didn't seem clear.

So the problem was the error "AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'adv'", although everything seemed right.

And actually, everything was right, the problem was individual to another PC, where "import wx.adv" resulted in a segmentation fault.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'4.0.7.post2 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5'
>>> wx.adv.NotificationMessage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'adv'
>>>
```

Or is there any other "non intrusive" notification method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try importing this and run this again

```
import wx.adv
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried this and gotten a segmentation fault. But now I've tried it on a different computer and it works. So this was the solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As @arvind8 points out it is a separate import.

At its simplest:

```
import wx
import wx.adv
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title="Hello, world!")
frame.Show()
m=wx.adv.NotificationMessage("My message","The text I wish to show")
#m.Show(timeout = m.Timeout_Never)
m.Show(timeout = m.Timeout_Auto)
#m.Show(timeout = 5)

app.MainLoop()
```

Note:
the timeout function for the message takes either a number of seconds or one of 2 pre-set values `Never` or `Auto`.
`Auto` is the default.